# Spark - pivot function with new aliases for new columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pivot

I have to translate this sql query into Spark API in Scala. My env is databricks: Spark 3.1.2 and Scala 2.12. My sql query:

```
                select *
                from my_table
                PIVOT (
                SUM(column99) AS i
                FOR column100 IN ('value1' as value1_p, 'value2' as value2_p,
                                'value3' as value3_p, 'value2' as value4_p,
                                 etc. more values))
```

Expected output should be:

| Column1 | Column1 | Column1 | Column3-100 | value1_p | value1_p | value1_p | value4-30_p |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 4 | 2 | 3 | sum(column99) | sum(column99) | sum(column99) | sum(column99) |
| 3 | 2 | 2 | 3 | sum(column99) | sum(column99) | sum(column99) | sum(column99) |

I have tried to implement such way but struggling with transformation inside groupBy and pivot.

```
val groupCols = tfe_filter.drop("column100", "column99").columns.map(col(_))
val pivot_table=tfe_filter.groupBy(groupCols:_*).pivot("column100").agg(sum("column99"))
```

How should I proceed futher to complete my transformation? How can I add suffix to each pivoted columns in automated way?